# Webp very low quality when converting transparent PNG image files

Tags: optimization, image-processing, png, pageload, webp

I want to use Webp and get my images much small, at last for serving them to chrome browsers. I've download many types of conversion tools, including the official one. I tried to convert PNG with Alpha transparency and get awful results. See image below..

[image]

According to what I see on many websites, it shold handle transparency incredibly well. I wanted to know if you know why I get these kind of results and what I need to do or what tool I need to produce high quality webp transparent images that will replace my png ones.

Second, I wanted to know the comparability. Should I server those images only for chrome uses? - OF course the most important issue is the image quality outpu.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of WebP library/binary, which didn't have alpha support. So the images you see have alpha channel stripped.

Try again with the latest release v0.2.0:
http://code.google.com/p/webp/downloads/list